# Why are the effects of a function inside my closure not persisting?

Tags: javascript, closures

I have the following code (edited for brevity). When I call `addAttribute` from an instance of `Node`, the `attributes` map updates correctly *within* the `attributes` function, but the moment the code steps out of that function the updates are lost.

I would expect, given that `attributes` is closed over, that this would not occur. Any thoughts as to why? Any advice here would be greatly appreciated!

```
const Node = function(nodeData) {
  let attributes = new Map();

  const addAttribute = function (attribute) {
    attributes = new Map([...attributes, ...attribute]);
    console.log(attributes); // Works correctly, as expected.
  }

  console.log(attributes); // Shows empty map, decidedly not as expected.

  return {
    attributes,
    addAttribute,
  }
}
```

Comment: `addAttribute` is not called until after the function finishes. Your question is like: `let attributes = new Map(); console.log(attributes); // why is it empty`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Ah, this makes sense. Any way around it?

Comment: It's not clear why you're expecting the Map to be populated at the point that it's logged, or what exactly you're looking to accomplish, could you elaborate some on the sort of output you're expecting? Were you hoping to be able to log the stuff inside the Map *before* the Map gets populated?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your code? There are no closures by the way

Comment: @CertainPerformance the log is just for illustration. Later on, after I have instantiated one or more `Node`s, I would like to use `addAttribute` an arbitrary number of times to add, well, attributes to the instance. This is failing.

Comment: could it be that you are trying to create a class Object? either you use the new "class" syntax, or attributes should be associated to the class with this.attributes = ...
and than, you can change and persist it.

Comment: @DDomen `addAttributes` closes over `attributes`, does it not? Does it matter that I return that function in an object?

Comment: @Leviathan actually hate classes unfortunately. I never use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `Node` it returns an object with an `attributes` property. That property holds a copy of the value `attributes` variable (which is an empty Map).

Later you call `addAttribute` which overwrites the `attributes` variable with another new Map.

This doesn't change the original Map that was assigned the the `attributes` property earlier.

---

Remember: The `attributes` property holds a copy of the original value of the `attributes` variable. It **doesn't** hold a reference to the variable.

---

If you want to update the Map that was returned then you need to **mutate the existing Map** and not replace the value of the `attributes` variable.

e.g. `attributes.set( attribute[0], attribute[1] )`

---

To simplify that, without the closure:

```js
{

  const original = new Map([
    [1, "one"],
    [2, "two"]
  ]);
  const other = new Map([...original, [3, "three"]]);
  console.log("original is unchanged", [...original.values()]);

};

{

  const original = new Map([
    [1, "one"],
    [2, "two"]
  ]);
  original.set(3, "three");
  console.log("original is mutated", [...original.values()]);

}
```